# C# and MongoDB - Optimized batch insert and update

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following objects

```
public class FileMetadata
{
    public string FileID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public class HashEntry
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public UInt32 Hash { get; set; }
    public List<FileMetadata> FileList { get; set; }
}
```

I will have a bunch of `HashEntry` objects mostly around 40,000 of them, and I want to create a new `HashEntry` in MongoDB and add the `inputFile` to it only if the `HashEntry` does not exist already. If it exists just add the file to its `FileList` collection.

```
var collection = _LocalDB.GetCollection<HashEntry>("Files");

foreach (var item in HashList)
{    
    var filter = Builders<HashEntry>.Filter.Eq("Hash", item);
    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

    if (result.Count==0)
    {
        var newHash = new HashEntry();
        newHash.FileList = new List<FileMetadata>();

        newHash.Hash = item;
        newHash.FileList.Add(inputFile);
        collection.InsertOne(newHash);
    }
    else
    {
        var update = Builders<HashEntry>.Update.Push("FileList",inputFile);
        collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter,update);
    }
}
```

The code I'm using takes long time to finish, eventhough I'm running the server locally. Does MongoDB natively support some feature for this? Like saving a new document and only inserting new fields without deleting older data? This is supposed to work like an inverted index.

Comment: Did you look into [bulk writes](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/writing/#bulk-writes) ?

Comment: Now I temporarily add new hashes into a list and insert them that way, its working better now. But can't I just use a method to create the hash and add a new file to its FileList or just add the new file if the hash is already present?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InsertBatch function to reach this effect. 
Here is a little sample for it:

```
List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
var collection = _LocalDB.GetCollection<HashEntry>("Files");

foreach (var item in HashList)
{    
    var filter = Builders<HashEntry>.Filter.Eq("Hash", item);
    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

    if (result.Count==0)
    {
        var newHash = new HashEntry();
        newHash.FileList = new List<FileMetadata>();

        newHash.Hash = item;
        newHash.FileList.Add(inputFile);
        batch.Add(newHash.ToBson());
    }
    else
    {
        var update = Builders<HashEntry>.Update.Push("FileList",inputFile);
        collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter,update);
    }
}

collection.InsertBatch(batch.ToArray());
```

This insert all the HashEntry in step. It is much much faster